# Maxing 4-6 Bonded NIC

Tags: networking

I have been load testing different configurations of hardware and using a Dell R610 w/ 4SSD in RAID 0, 24GB ram and 2 L5640 (2.26Ghz w/12MB L3).

I was able to get great performance out of the RAID and the 4 bonded network controllers but while streaming to 2400 simultaneous connections using 500 different video files the CPU would max out, which would interrupt the media streaming when we reached around 2.5Gb out.

I tried upgrading the CPU and RAM to 72GB ram and an X5675 processor but the R610 threw an error on bootup "power required exceeds psu wattage" so I am going to go back and play with the HP DL180 but it only has 2 1Gb network adapters, which we are already able to max out so am thinking of getting a 4 port 1Gb NIC card.

So I see this one here from StarTech:
http://smile.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Express-Gigabit-Ethernet-ST1000SPEX42/dp/B00AWP9MGG/ref=sr_1_9?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1421345809&sr=1-9

And this one from HP:http://smile.amazon.com/HP-NC364T-Gigabit-Server-Adptr/dp/B000P0NX3G/ref=sr_1_2?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1421347044&sr=1-2

Price isn't a huge concern considering the importance of the device, but I do like staying with name brands when possible (which is the less expensive option in this case).

The big thing I noticed is that the StarTech has 4 controllers, while the HP only has 2, so I assume that perhaps the max output of the HP would actually be limited to 2Gb, but could do that over any 2 ports or combination of ports, where the StarTech could potentially do all 4 ports maxing out at 1Gb?

The datacenter I am putting it at doesn't have 10Gb connections, but I can get additional 1Gb ports connected for $50/each so it seems like a decent win to have the option of having 6 if needed.

Just checking to see if there are other things I need to be thinking about such as on board RAM buffers and such.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't trust Realtek chipsets for a production environment.

On the other hand I have multiple of those HP NICs (Intel chipsets) running on ESXi servers and I haven't encountered any problems. They are used mainly for iSCSI storage traffic in LACP mode (bonding), but in pairs of 2.

According to HP they can provide 4Gbit aggregate throughput.
http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/networking/nc364t/index.html

What exactly maxes out your CPU?
The bonding driver?

What NICs do you currently have? Don't they have TCP Offloading so that they won't use your cpu cycles?

Comment: The media streaming server is what maxes out the processor. That being said after switching to SSD from 15K drives, we were able to get additional users connected keeping the CPU at a lower usage for a while. Thanks for showing me that link.

Comment: If your bottleneck is the streaming server itself then you probably won't get much more by switch the NICs.

Comment: Except I was switching out the CPUs, adding 48GB RAM to it. Otherwise you would certainly be right. I found a local dealer with that HP card for $45 that I can throw into the HP and try again.

Comment: So a little off topic, but I was going to swap out the CPUs and didn't have any thermal paste at the office. I was thinking about bringing some in from home and for some reason the idea of toothpaste came to mind. I am certainly NOT going to do that, EVER, but I did google it just for fun. Turns out it is not nearly as bad as I thought: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/386066-33-toothpaste-thermal-paste